# localStorage value gets wiped out by paginator NaN

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a function called `onPageChange` that stores the currentPage in localStorage and this part works, but if I reload the page then it clears out the value in localStorage. I added an alert that will says if I click page 4 and reload. `CURRENT PAGE IS 4`, but after the page loads completely, the value where 4 was retrieved from gets replaced with NaN.  How can I stop this from happening? The goal is to go back to component and load up the last page they were on. When a user logs in, I set the localStorage value to page 1 to reset it.

```
currentPage;

  ngOnInit() {
    this.currentPage = parseInt(localStorage.getItem("currentPage"));
    alert("CURRENT PAGE IS:  " + this.currentPage);


    this.userId = this.authService.getUserId();

    this.isLoading = true;
    this.spinner.show();
    const postsPerPage = 10;

    let listingRoute = "main";
    this.submitListingService
      .getListings(false, false, listingRoute, postsPerPage, this.currentPage, null)
      .pipe(takeUntil(this.destroy))
      .subscribe(postData => {
        this.isLoading = false;
        this.totalPosts = postData.maxPosts;
        console.log(this.totalPosts);
        console.log(postData);

        this.posts = postData.posts;
        this.posts1 = postData.posts;
        this.posts3 = postData.posts;
        this.filteredPosts = postData.posts;
      });

  }


  onPageChange(currentPage: PageEvent) {
    let counter: number;
    counter = 0;
    counter++;
    localStorage.setItem("currentPage", currentPage.toString());

    let newPage: number;
    newPage = parseInt(currentPage.toString());

    const postsPerPage = 10;
    console.log("currentPAGE" + newPage);
    if (this.filtersEnabled) {
      let listingRoute = "filter";
      this.submitListingService
        .getListings(
          this.buyItNowEnabled,
          this.privateAuctionEnabled,
          listingRoute,
          postsPerPage,
          newPage,
          null
        )
        .pipe(takeUntil(this.destroy))
        .subscribe(postData => {
          this.isLoading = false;
          if (!this.isLoading) {
            this.totalPosts = postData.maxPosts;
            console.log(this.totalPosts);
            this.isLoading = true;
            this.posts = postData.posts;
            this.posts1 = postData.posts;
            window.scroll(0, 0);
            this.posts3 = postData.posts;
            this.filteredPosts = postData.posts;
            localStorage.setItem("currentPage", newPage.toString());
          }
        });
    } else if (!this.filtersEnabled) {
      let listingRoute = "main";
      this.submitListingService
        .getListings(false, false, listingRoute, postsPerPage, newPage, null)
        .pipe(takeUntil(this.destroy))
        .subscribe(postData => {
          this.isLoading = false;
          this.totalPosts = postData.maxPosts;
          console.log(this.totalPosts);
          this.isLoading = true;
          this.posts = postData.posts;
          this.posts1 = postData.posts;
          window.scroll(0, 0);
          this.posts3 = postData.posts;
          this.filteredPosts = postData.posts;
        });
    }
  }
```

paginator

```
<ngb-pagination (pageChange)="onPageChange($event)" [collectionSize]="this.totalPosts" *ngIf="!this.mobile"
          [(page)]="this.currentPage" [boundaryLinks]="true"></ngb-pagination>
```

Comment: Is PageEvent an object? Looking at the angular material docs for it - https://material.angular.io/components/paginator/api. If so you need to save the `currentPage.pageIndex` to localstorage. Otherwise you are trying to call `parseInt` on an object (or an object that has been stringified -  `"[object Object]"`).

Comment: I added in beginning of OnPageChange() ```alert(currentPage.pageIndex);``` and it returns undefined, which is kind of weird since it has no problem finding the property https://postimg.cc/B8bMwhs6  ```currentPage.pageIndex is undefined``` I added paginator as reference too above

Comment: Yeah so you are trying to add an object to local storage. `localStorage.setItem("currentPage", currentPage.toString());` This is fine but you would need to parse it using `JSON.stringify` && `JSON.parse`. Or you can just add the page to local storage, `localStorage.setItem("currentPage", currentPage['pageIndex'].toString());`

Comment: It no longer gives me NaN, but for some reason when I reload the page, it's resetting the localStorage value to 1 now. I'm not reassigning the value so I don't know if it's taking the first page from ```currentPage: PageEvent``` on page load , storing the value and overwriting page before load or if it's something else.

Comment: Throw a `debugger` in your onPageChange function, might be called when the page loads. If so you can wrap the local storage assignment in some logic to prevent it.

Comment: I used the debugger and what is happening is when I change the page to 4 for example. I reload the page, alert in ngOnInit() 
```CURRENT PAGE IS:  4``` . After that, it hits OnPageChange when reloading the page and it resets it like this (debugger screenshot): https://postimg.cc/944Qbq89